# AngularJS access $http return json array

Tags: angularjs

i have older post which i deleted i solved it there.
I have other issue:

I have this data array came from PHP with $http(i use console.log):
[image]

I can't access that data with ng-repeat:

```
ibids.controller("auctions",function($http){


        var req = {
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'includes/bids.php',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'json'
         },
         data: 'q=getAuctions'
        }

        $http(req).then(function(req){
            console.log(req);
            var auctionslist = req.data;
        }, function(){


        });



});
```

html:

```
  <body ng-controller="auctions as auction">
    <input type="text" value="test" ng-model="man">
    {{man}}
    <hr>
    <div class="search" >
      <input type="text">
      <div class="res" ng-repeat="x in auction.auctionslist">
        {{x}}
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
```

What is wrong here ? i recive json data from php and perfect assign to data array in $http .when i use console.log(req) this is what you see in the pictures and its recive the json array perfect.
i don't know how to use ng-repeat on that data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use $scope and add a property on it for this data and use it in template

```
ibids.controller("auctions",function($http, $scope){


    var req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'includes/bids.php',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'json'
     },
     data: 'q=getAuctions'
    }

    $http(req).then(function(req){
        console.log(req);
        $scope.auctions = req.data;
    }, function(){


    });

});
```

and in html

```
 <body ng-controller="auctions">
<input type="text" value="test" ng-model="man">
{{man}}
<hr>
<div class="search" >
  <input type="text">
  <div class="res" ng-repeat="auction in auctions">
    {{auction}}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ok,now i see the data,but i see only the first array any idea ? when i do auction.name for example, i get twice the same name

Comment: It is because your data contains two item with same name as given in your screenshot

Comment: OHhhh i just notice sorry! i am not focus. very thanks now its all good :)